# Chrome Mobile with Angular using GET instead of POST

Tags: android, angularjs, google-chrome

When using Chrome on Android (Firefox doesn't seem affected, and I don't know about iOS) I have a login form in AngularJS that when submitted, it doesn't use the `$http.post('/user/login', {})` method but instead uses a `GET` method.

The login form is at http://example/#/login whereas the GET request is http://example/user/login The only place /user/login is found in the code is in the $http.post('/user/login', {}) call.

Is this a known Chrome or Angular issue? Is there a way to find out which is causing the problem? Is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** - There's one way I've found around this, and it's to press the Login button multiple times.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker of your code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can try. The issue is that it requires a post to a waiting server, so it may not work out.